# overlapping and centering divs in html/css

Tags: css, html

In a html page, I would like to vertically center 2 small divs above a bigger one, like below:

```
+-----------div1-----------+
|                          |
|                          | 
| +-2-+              +-3-+ |
| |   |              |   | |
| +---+              +---+ |
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

div1 will contains an image of unknown size, so I can't use absolute positionning.

I have tried many combinations of css attributes, without success.

Any idea?

Comment: *2 small divs above a bigger one* : above or inside?

Comment: You can use [absolute positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/g8psN/).

Comment: Thanks Vucko. I thought absolute positionning required pixels only. But as I know the height of div2 and div3, you're right, I can use absolute positionning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your inside div's (div2 and div3) have got a static width and height, you could use this solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="text" />
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#left,
#right{
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background-color: red;
}
#left{
    left: 20px;
}
#right{   
    right: 20px;
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aPJ8u/7/

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same answer

Comment: To improve upon this answer, you can now simply use `calc()` to solve the problem that `top` and `margin-top` are solving here. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZ2qU/1/)

Comment: note: calc() is css3 which issn't supported by all browsers (Older versions of IE)

Comment: OP says `I can't use absolute positionning.` and your css has `position: absolute;`...please explain!!

Comment: OP says that he can't use absolute positioning because div1 contains an image of a unknown height. My solution shows that you CAN use absolute positioning regardless of the height of the image inside div1. I think my jsfiddle makes my point...

Comment: @Jop : yeah it does make the point...that why i wanted to know! :)

Comment: Thanks. This is the same solution as Vucko's link above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/g8psN/2/

Addition for .main

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Then `float` the child elements left and right.

Comment: this won't work when you add an image inside the main div like so: http://jsfiddle.net/g8psN/3/

Comment: "div1 will contains an image"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without having to worry about the consequences of absolute positioning is to use floats. The method of vertical alignment I am proposing requires you to know the heights of the vertically aligned elements. If this is not possible, we can figure out another solution.

### HTML

Simply place the elements inside of the wrapping `div`.

```
<div id="test1">
    <div id="test2"></div>
    <div id="test3"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

The `width` and `height` of `#test1` do not need to be set. Neither do the `background-color`s.

```
#test1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#test2 {
    float: left;
}

#test3 {
    float: right;
}

#test2, #test3 {
    margin-top: calc(50% - 25px);    
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XASUs/)

Answer (score 0):

i guess m late in answering...here is another solution  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/6zaVj/6/)

**CSS**

```
    .outer {
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    /**change this as per your need */
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.div1 {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    padding: 10px;
}
.div2 {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
.div3 {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="outer">
    <div class="defaultdiv div1">div on left
    </div>
    <div class="defaultdiv div2"></div>
    <div class="defaultdiv div3">div on right
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reformat your CSS. You can do it automatically with the "Tidy Up" option in JSFiddle.

Comment: was doing that only mate...if only u could have waited for one more minute!! :)

Comment: Muuuch better. Although, this really doesn't align in the middle. You need to take into account the height of the thing you're centering.

Answer (score 0):

@Laurent Use `display:table` and `display:table-cell`: http://jsfiddle.net/nLdU5/